# import and remaping tables without adding primary key and indexes

Tags: oracle, impdp

I am trying to import a dump to a database. the dump has a table called table1 which already exists in the database , that I was I used remap_table.

```
impdp schema/pass@server remap_table = table1:table_BR1 directory=TEST_DIR1 dumpfile=table_BR1.dmp logfile=table1.log
```

However the problem I am facing , its also creating the primary key and index, causing errors "constraints already exists"
In my real scenario I have several tables.

My question , is there way that I can remap the tables without adding the primary keys and indexex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IMPDP, you could use:

```
CONTENT=DATA_ONLY
```

**DATA_ONLY loads only table row data into existing tables; no database objects are created**.

Other ways are,

You could explicitly specify **not** to import the **indexes** and **constraints** as command line arguments.

```
rows=Y indexes=N constraints=N
```

This would import only the data and not indexes and constraints.

Also, to suppress the error messages, you could ignore them:

```
IGNORE=Y
```

To see a list of all import commands, do:

```
impdp help=y
```

Alternatively, if you know the **INDEX** names, you could use the **[EXCLUDE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL911)** command.

For example,

```
EXCLUDE=INDEX:"LIKE 'DEPT%'"
```

This will exclude all indexes whose names start with dept.

Comment: I am using impdp  , can I use igonre = Y and indexes = N ?

Comment: You could try `CONTENT=DATA_ONLY` in IMPDP. Let me know once you try.